# Include Tasks of Role By Tag Or Filter In Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible

How can I specify only a subset of the tasks of a role for inclusion?

Say, I want to include the tasks from the role `foobar`, but only the ones tagged by `baz`:

```
  tasks:
  - import_role:
      name: foobar
    tags:
      - baz
```

The above does not work, because Ansible will interpret this as "only include foobar if tag `baz` is specified" instead of "only include tasks with the tag `baz`"

Is there some mechanism that allows to specify only a subset of role tasks for inclusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: ***"Is there some mechanism that allows specifying only a subset of role tasks for inclusion?"***

A: The only option is the parameter [*tasks_from*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html#parameter-tasks_from). As you have already found out the selection by tags is available from the command line (--tags) only.